# Repairing top of damaged door trim

Tags: repair, door-frame

[image: the damaged section seems to be just hanging on]
Hi, some fools did pull ups on my door frame and the top section gave way. It won't budge when I try to push it back up (although I didn't put much force into it) , so I was thinking that perhaps the best way to go about repairing it would be to tear it off and use some adhesive (Elmer's wood glue?) to put it back on.

Does that seem to be a reasonable course of action and are there any considerations I should keep in mind beforehand? I haven't really dealt with anything of this sort before so all advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the "door frame" but rather door *trim* and specifically it is crown molding. It will be nailed or screwed. Get up on a ladder and examine it from the top. Take pictures of what you see.

You will probably have to remove this element of the trim and reinstall it, but don't be in a hurry to tackle this. You could cause a lot of damage if you don't do it properly. Do it properly and you may not even have much (or any) touch up painting. Do it wrong, and you will make a mess that will require a professional to restore and will cost a pretty penny.

Honestly, a competent trim carpenter should be brought in to fix this. It appears another element has been pulled from the wall, and there is a trim piece missing, or paint missing, from the end of the horizontal trim above the door. It looks like the door trim was not complete. Is this a new house?

Comment: Ah, you're exactly right the screws that are holding it are there but bent outwards which explains how it's hanging like that and why it won't really budge. It's a fairly old apartment too.

Comment: Bent screws cannot be unscrewed and will have to be cut probably with a grinder with a cut-off wheel, a Dremel, or small circular saw.  *Skilled* use of a reciprocating saw might do it. They might be able to be cut by hand with a sharp hacksaw blade, but probably a power tool will be needed.

Comment: If you can cut the screws and leave a straight section from the cut to the head, then the crown molding will come away and you can unscrew the part with the head. The remaining part may then be free to be unscrewed using pliers or locking pliers (vise-grips).